# How to show search result in search.php page using WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a basic custom WordPress template. Here I a have search form like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form"  role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search" name="q">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default search" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Now when I search something it's going to home.php page (website homepage) but I need to call the search.php file so that all search result will be shown on search.php file.

List of files I'm using currently:

1. 404.php  2. footer.php   3. header.php  4. home.page  5. index.php (empty)
2. page.php  7.search.php  8.single.php  9.style.css  10.screenshot.png

How can I show the result in search.php page?

Note: New To WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I need to replace the `name="q"` with `name="s"`

Thanks.